# $\nu<<\mu$ where $\nu$ is arbitary signed measure and $\mu$ is $\sigma$- finite measure then $\exists f$ such that $d\nu =fd\mu$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

> If $\nu<<\mu$ where $\nu$ is arbitary signed measure and $\mu$ is $\sigma$- finite measure then $\exists f$ which is extended  $\mu $ integrable $f:X\to [-\infty,\infty]$ such that $d\nu =fd\mu$

I know that if $\nu$ is $\sigma$-finite then I can directly use Radon Nikodyme theorem to conclude . I am completely stuck here . Please If anyone give me how to start to complete this problem I would be thankful

Any Help will be appreciated

Comment: LaTeX hint ... use `\ll` to get $\ll$.

Comment: Hint : You can write $\nu=\nu^+-\nu^-$ where $\nu^+\ll\mu$, $\nu^-\ll\mu$ and they are both $\sigma$-finite measures. Then applying the 
Radon Nikodyme theorem to both and taking $f$ to be the difference of the two function you obtain should work.

Comment: I agree with P Quinton, however are they both $\sigma$-finite?
$\nu$ is not said to be $\sigma$-finite. If it is, we are good to go, otherwise, I think we are able to find a counter example.

Comment: I guess the OP is concerned about the result when $\nu$ is not sigma-finite.  But if $d\nu = f\;d\mu$ where $f$ is $\mu$-integrable, then $\nu$ is finite.  So the OP needs to add explanation.

Comment: Also, $\nu$ is said to be a signed measure, and such is often defined to be finite.

Comment: @GEdgar Dear Sir F is extended $\mu $ integrable . Please Help me

Comment: OK, only one of $\nu^+, \nu^-$ can be infinite, so we may as well do the case $\nu \ge 0$.  In that case we want to know: is there a nonnegative $\mu$-measurable $f$ so that $\nu(E) = \int_E f\;d\mu$ for all measurable sets $E$.  Both $\nu$ and $f$ are allowed the value $+\infty$.  And since $\mu$ is sigma-finite, we can reduce to the case where $\mu$ is finite.

Answer (score 1):

The result you need can be found in Theorem 19.27 of

Hewitt, Edwin; Stromberg, Karl, *Real and abstract analysis. A modern treatment of the theory of functions of a real variable*, Berlin-Heidelberg-New York: Springer-Verlag. VIII, 476 p. with 8 fig. (1965). [ZBL0137.03202](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0137.03202).

Once you reduce to the case $\nu \ge 0$ and $\mu$ finite, the main lemma required is:

> **Lemma 19.26.**
>   Let $\mu, \nu$ be measures on $(X, \mathcal A)$ such that $\mu(X) < \infty$ and $\nu \ll \mu$.  Then there exists a set $E \in \mathcal A$ such that:
>   (for all $A \in \mathcal A$ such that $A \subseteq E$) $\nu(A) = 0$ or $\nu(A) = \infty$
>   (for all $A \in \mathcal A$ such that $A \subseteq E$) $\mu(A) = 0$ if $\nu(A) = 0$
>   $\nu$ is sigma-finite on the complement $X \setminus E$.

Once you have this Lemma, then for Radon-Nikodym derivative, take $f = \infty$ on $E$ and use the usual RN therem on $X \setminus E$